# Why does syntax partially disappear when removing @ from iskeyword?

Tags: ruby, vim, syntax, keyword

When I add this to my vimrc:

```
set iskeyword-=@
```

It removes some syntax. I've only tested this in viml and ruby code. What's the reason for this? I've included images to show the effect in viml code.

[image: Before removing @]
[image: After removing @]

EDIT: How would I go about removing it without affecting syntax? The reason why I removed it was to make it easier to select `"$@"` as a word. Anyone can offer a solution to this problem or an alternative way of doing that is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `'isfname'`, which `'iskeyword'` points to:

> If the character is '@', all characters where isalpha() returns TRUE are included. … To include '@' itself use "@-@".

`@` (64) isn’t actually in the character set to begin with for me:

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

but if it somehow got in there for you, you can add a part starting with a caret to exclude it:

```
set iskeyword+=^@-@
```